# How to solve crossword puzzle by Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, word-embeddings

If we have enough crossword puzzles with answers in our database, is that possible to build a Machine Learning model to solve crossword puzzles?

I read the paper:

[Learning to Understand Phrases by Embedding the Dictionary](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00548)

But this paper is mostly about finding the word for each question. How to put the constraints, i.e. word length and letter sharing, into the algorithm? I was thinking about nearest neighbor to find all possible words and filter by the constraints. Is there any other straightforward way?

Comment: Straightforward way is to just search all strings for a given word, no machine learning required

Comment: @rep_ho No given words. You only have a list of hints.

Comment: ah, sorry, I thought you are talking about those crossword puzzles where you are looking for words in a bunch of letters in 8 directions. Anyway, if you have candidate words for each hint, you can use some search and constraint satisfaction algorithms to find the correct solution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction , no learning required. That shouldn't be a problem, IMO the challenging task would be to process and understand hints

Comment: @rep_ho That's the problem, finding all possible the candidate words for each hint can be tricky. What the model can produce is a word embedding, which may not be corresponding to an exact word.

Comment: @rep_ho: That is a word-search, not a cross-word.